# Regex: Simplify parameters of a java method (java.lang.String, xyz.Clazz -> String, Clazz)

Tags: java, regex

I need some help with a simple regex. The goal is to simplify the parameters of a Java method.

Input:  `java.util.Locale arg0, java.lang.String arg1, java.lang.Object... arg2`

Output: `Locale arg0, String arg1, Object... arg2`

This is how I started, the regex doesn't work yet.

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("([a-z].*?)[A-Z]", Pattern.DOTALL);
String str = "java.util.Locale arg0, java.lang.String arg1, java.lang.Object... arg2";
// now replace all groups (java.util., java.lang.) with an empty string
// System.out.println(regex.matcher(str).replaceAll(""));
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following prints `Locale arg0, String arg1, Object... arg2`:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(\\w+\\.(?=\\w))+");
String str = "java.util.Locale arg0, java.lang.String arg1, java.lang.Object... arg2";
System.err.println(regex.matcher(str).replaceAll(""));
```

The regex will match everything up to the last dot such that the following character (not consumed by the regex, due to the lookahead), is a word character, e.g. a letter. That means that it also works with the varargs, because you have `Object...` where the dot is followed by another dot, rather than a word character.

Comment: Are you sure?  It gives me "Locale arg0, String arg1, .. arg2".

Comment: I've made an edit that works, but maybe I can find something simpler.

Comment: Perfect, +1 from me.  Might be worth explaining why this lookahead operator does the job too?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your pattern is pretty simple:

```
(\w+\s\w+)
```

See [a demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sD6iK5/1).